# How to open Radial-Menu-Widget in onCreate instead of on Button Click event?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have implemented this [Radial-Menu-Widget](https://code.google.com/p/radial-menu-widget/) in my project. But this opens the widget on button click event as

```
testButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            pieMenu.show(v);
        }
});
```

I want to show this Widget in onCreate instead of on Button Click event. Is there any tricky way to execute the above code without any click event?

Comment: Is there any tricky way to execute the above code without any click event.

Comment: the question is: when do you want to open it?

Comment: How to Open Radial-Menu-Widget in onCreate instead of on Button Click event

Comment: @FabioAngela I want to open this menu without clicking any button or view. thats the question

Answer (score 0):

i don't know in details your radial widget, anyway i suppose you should call it into the Resume event, passing maybe the coordinate of center point (it depend on your widget)

to prevent reopen the radial (if you don't want it opens again when you show an already created activity), you have to set a boolean to store the widget state (shown/hidden) and prevent to call the show method again if you don't want to

Answer (score 0):

You may call a separate function from within the OnCreate function and With the help of post method we can wait until all necessary start up life cycle methods get completed.

```
private void ShowThePieMenu(RadialMenuWidget v) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayoutname, null);
    layout.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            pieMenu.show(layout);
        }
    });
}
```